# What is a regular tree

Tags: binary-tree

I will built a none binary tree with python
Input format. The first line contains the number of vertices . The second line contains  integers from −1 to  − 1 - the parent of the vertices. If the ith vertex of them (0 ≤  ≤  - 1) is −1, then vertex  is the root, otherwise it is the index starting at 0 of the parent of the th vertex. Make sure there is only one root. Make sure that the input represents a tree.
Out put format. Out put the height of the tree
Input:

5

4 -1 4 1 1

Output:

3
Input means there are 5 nodes with numbers from 0 to 4, node 0 is the child of node 4, node 1 is the root, node 2 is the child of node 4, node 3 is the child of node 1 and node 4 is the child of node 1. To see this, let's write the node numbers from 0 to 4 on one line and the numbers given in the input on the second line below:

0 1 2 3 4

4 -1 4 1 1

Now we can see, node 1 is the root, because -1 corresponds to node 1 in the second line. We also know that nodes 3 and 4 are children of root node 1. We also know that nodes 0 and 2 are children of node 4.

1
3  4
0  2
The height of this tree is 3, because the number of vertices on the path from root 1 to leaf 2 is 3.

Comment: How does the title relate to the code challenge you have posted? The word "regular" doesn't even occur in the text? Why is this question tagged with `binary-tree` when you write you are building a non-binary tree? What is your question? Is there something you don't understand in this code challenge?

Comment: There's no question in the actual question

Comment: Voting to close. Asker has apparently gone on holiday.

Answer (score 1):

As were mentioned in the comments: there's no question in the actual question body. The question might get deleted, in case it does not, it worthwhile to answer the actual question from the title.

A tree has very strict mathematical definition:
*A tree is connected graph without loops*

A non-trivial thing to point out is that most Computer scientists don't use that definition instead relying on
"a Tree(actually a Node) is certain data plus several instances of self." This definition is confusing because thing can't have different data and itself be like it's children in all regards cause children have children that previous parent wouldn't have.
So it's hard to proof that they are the same i.e. Node is substritue definition of a tree. It really is not and it takes extra lengthy check on each joining of nodes to verify there's no cycle with something like Floyd-Warshall algo. So Tree and TreeNode are fundamentally different things. However you only use Nodes, as they have ownership of the entire tree underneath them.

Here's a nice definition of a tree in Python:

```
    T = TypeVar('T')
class Node(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value_type : Type[T], parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = set()
        self.value = value_type()
    def add_child(self, child)->None:
        child.set_parent = self
        self.children.add(child)
    def add_child_x(self, child)->bool:
        if child not in self.children:
            self.add_child(child)
            return True
        return False
    def add_children(self, children : list)->None:
        for child in children:
            self.add_child(child)
    def remove_child(self, child)->bool:
        if child in self.children:
            child.set_parent(None)
            self.children.remove(child)
            return True
        return False
    def set_parent(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
    def sever(self):
        self.set_parent(None)
    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def outstr(self, indent = 0):
        outstr = ''
        if indent:
            outstr += '\n' +(' '*indent) + '↑___'
        elif not self.parent:
            outstr += '*'
        outstr += str(self.value)
        for child in self.children:
            outstr += child.outstr(indent+len(str(self.value)))
        return outstr
    def print(self):
        print(self.outstr())

    def get_root(self):
        back = self
        while back.parent is not None:
            back = back.parent
        return back
        
    def get_leafs(self):
        stack = [self]
        leafs = list()
        while stack:
            node = stack.pop()
            if node.children:
                stack.extend(node.children)
            else:
                leafs.append(node)
        return leafs
```